# sudo: /etc/sudoers is owned by uid 501, should be 0

Tags: password, sudo, authorization

To run programs as sudo without password, I edited /etc/sudoers with wrong content.

Then I re-edited it with Mac's default text editor(course sudo cannot be used when /etc/sudoers is wrong).

I tried to run sudo agin, and get this error:

```
sudo: /etc/sudoers is owned by uid 501, should be 0
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
```

What should I do? I cannot remember the root password (maybe I haven't ever set root password before).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can boot into single user mode by pressing <kbd>Cmd-S</kbd> on startup (see [OS X: How to start up in single-user or verbose mode](http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201573) for details) which should give you a root shell. Then run

```
mount -uw /
chown root:wheel /etc/sudoers
chmod 440 /etc/sudoers
reboot
```

to fix the problem and restart.

Answer (score 21):

You can fix this via AppleScript, without needing to reboot, or even log out & back in, or an existing root shell, or... All you need is a valid administrator password.

Run this command:

```
osascript -e 'do shell script "chown root:wheel /etc/sudoers; chmod 440 /etc/sudoers; chmod -N /etc/sudoers" with administrator privileges'
```

...and then authenticate as an administrator when requested.

Explanation: this is a bit indirect. It uses the shell command `osascript` to run a short AppleScript that uses the `do shell script` command to run a short shell script. The reason for the shell->AppleScript->shell thing is to use the `with administrator privileges` option, which has much the same effect as `sudo` but will work even if /etc/sudoers is completely messed up.

Comment: This one work best for me :)

Comment: Worked like a charm for me!!!

Comment: This helped me today

Answer (score 8):

For macOS Mojave, here is what worked for me:

1. Start up in recovery mode (Cmd+R during boot up)
2. Disk Utilities > Select Macintosh HD, and Mount
3. Close Disk Utilities
4. Utilities > Terminal
5. Type: `chown root:wheel "/Volumes/Macintosh HD/etc/sudoers"`
6. Reboot

You may also need to change the ownership of ts, back in the Terminal:

```
sudo su
sudo chown -R root:wheel /var/db/sudo/ts/
```

Comment: Why do you reboot the machine afterwards? And also, why are you doing `sudo su`?

Answer (score 6):

1. Open `Directory Utility` (/System/Library/CoreServices/).
2. Click the lock icon to unlock it, then enter your administrator name and password.
3. Do one of the following:

   - Choose Edit > Enable Root User, then enter a root user password in the Password and Verify fields.
   - Choose Edit > Change Root Password, then enter a new root user password. You don't need an old password
4. Login to Root
5. Modify sudoers with `visudo` like stated in the file:

   The original file looks like this:

   ```
   # sudoers file.
   #
   # This file MUST be edited with the 'visudo' command as root.
   # Failure to use 'visudo' may result in syntax or file permission errors
   # that prevent sudo from running.
   #
   # See the sudoers man page for the details on how to write a sudoers file.
   #

   # Host alias specification

   # User alias specification

   # Cmnd alias specification

   # Defaults specification
   Defaults    env_reset
   Defaults    env_keep += "BLOCKSIZE"
   Defaults    env_keep += "COLORFGBG COLORTERM"
   Defaults    env_keep += "__CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING"
   Defaults    env_keep += "CHARSET LANG LANGUAGE LC_ALL LC_COLLATE LC_CTYPE"
   Defaults    env_keep += "LC_MESSAGES LC_MONETARY LC_NUMERIC LC_TIME"
   Defaults    env_keep += "LINES COLUMNS"
   Defaults    env_keep += "LSCOLORS"
   Defaults    env_keep += "SSH_AUTH_SOCK"
   Defaults    env_keep += "TZ"
   Defaults    env_keep += "DISPLAY XAUTHORIZATION XAUTHORITY"
   Defaults    env_keep += "EDITOR VISUAL"
   Defaults    env_keep += "HOME MAIL"

   # Runas alias specification

   # User privilege specification
   root    ALL=(ALL) ALL
   %admin  ALL=(ALL) ALL

   # Uncomment to allow people in group wheel to run all commands
   # %wheel    ALL=(ALL) ALL

   # Same thing without a password
   # %wheel    ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL

   # Samples
   # %users  ALL=/sbin/mount /cdrom,/sbin/umount /cdrom
   # %users  localhost=/sbin/shutdown -h now
   ```

   Info:

   ```
   machine:~ user$ ls -l /private/etc/sudoers 
   -r--r-----  1 root  wheel  1275 13 Jun  2012 /private/etc/sudoers
   ```

   Using `visudo` to modify the file corrects file permissions automatically
6. Disable the root user again.

Comment: If you find that you can't edit the file through the command line, open it using a GUI application like TextEdit. That will bypass the corrupt sudo configuration.

Comment: This worked for me after corrupting the sudoers file on Big Sur after updating. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Yosemite and earlier OSX keeps info on what permissions system files (i.e. files the OS installs) should be. [Apple's doc](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201560)

To restore this use Disk Utility.app.
Select the boot volume (by default called Macintosh HD) on the left hand side.
Click the Verify or Repair Disk Permissions - the latter will reapply the stored permissions.

To edit sudoers in the future I would use visudo which checks that the edit is valid

re the root password you probably have not set it before - the idea of sudo is that you never need to use it and Apple disables root login by default

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me: (No root password, but admin access required)

1. Created another admin account **test**
2. Manually set it's uid to 0 (right click on account > Advanced Options)
3. Restart the system, login via **test** (a lot of errors will pop-up, cancel/ok all of them)
4. Go to `cd /etc/` and `chown -R $(whoami) sudoers` (The sudo error will go away now, but to remove **test** account, we have to undo everything)
5. Restart the system and login with your normal account
6. Manually set **test** uid to 502 (or 500+something that is not taken by other admins)
7. Remove the **test** account

Comment: Thanks man you have saved me from nuking my work laptop. All of the above given methods doesn't work for enterprise/company laptop (as they need recovery key and other restrictions). Above method worked fine for me.

Comment: @DevesH glad I could help. I had the same issue with company device

Comment: Might be better to take note of the UID before step 2, and set it back to that number in step 6. Or even skip step 6 and remove the account directly.

Comment: @nohillside If possible, great. If I remember correctly, I wasn't able to remove it as long as it had UID 0.

Comment: Ah, ok, that might indeed be a problem.

Comment: This saved my life on my work laptop!! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

In Terminal:

1. Type `sh` or `sudo sh` (my case I accidentally set `chown -R /` so sudo is me, no need sudo anymore, using `sh`)
2. **In `sh`**, type `cd /var/db/sudo/`, then do `ls -ln` to check if its the same as these:

   ```
   total 0
   drwxr-xr-x  2 501  0   68 Oct 23 23:56 yourusername
   drwx------  3 501  0  102 Nov 24 00:57 ts
   ```
3. then type `ls -la` and you'll get these:

   ```
   total 0
   drwx--x--x   4 yourusername   wheel   136 Oct 23 23:56 .
   drwxr-xr-x  80 yourusername   wheel  2720 Nov 24 01:55 ..
   drwxr-xr-x   2 root  wheel    68 Oct 23 23:56 yourusername
   drwx------   3 root  wheel   102 Nov 24 00:57 ts
   ```

The results above shows that `yourusername` is set to `wheel`, which isn't supposed to. It should normally look like these:

```
total 0
drwx--x--x   4 root  wheel   136 Oct 23 23:56 .
drwxr-xr-x  80 root  wheel  2720 Nov 24 01:55 ..
drwxr-xr-x   2 root  wheel    68 Oct 23 23:56 yourusername
drwx------   3 root  wheel   102 Nov 24 00:57 ts
```

See the difference?

Now, we want to fix it. Here's what I did:

1. **Still in `sh`**, I typed `chown -R root:wheel /var/db/sudo/yourusername` to change it to **UID 0** instead of UID 501 as above case
2. Do the same for ts, `chown -R root:wheel /var/db/sudo/ts/`
   Now check again the permission with `ls -ln` and it should look like these:

   ```
   total 0
   drwxr-xr-x  2 0  0   68 Oct 23 23:56 dan
   drwx------  3 0  0  102 Nov 24 00:57 ts
   UID is now set to 0 and not 501.
   ```
3. Now we do the same for `..` and `.` by running `chown -R root:wheel /var/db/sudo/./` and then `chown -R root:wheel /var/db/sudo/../`, and you'll get results as **No. 4** above.

Now we want to fix `/etc/sudoers` owned by UID 501.

1. **Still in `sh`**, first check permission by running `ls -ln /private/etc/sudoers` and it should get this:

   ```
   -r--r-----  1 501  0  1563 Nov 14 17:53 /private/etc/sudoers
   ```

Notice the UID 501? We want it to become **UID 0**.

2. So, run this command `chown -R root:wheel /private/etc/sudoers` and then `ls -ln /private/etc/sudoers` again to check if the permission changes to this:

   ```
   -r--r-----  1 0  0  1563 Nov 14 17:53 /private/etc/sudoers
   ```

So try `sudo` as you would again and see if that does the trick.

With all that, I have to remind you that I am not be responsible for your machine after following these steps, but at least this what works for me.

Answer (score 2):

Great and simply for High Sierra- no SUDO, no recovery, just (verify/repair permissions)

1. First Step

```
diskutil resetUserPermissions / `id -u`
```

2. Second item
   Choose Folder via Finder -> Information -> unlock and choose Setting Wheel on the bottom-> Apply to enclosed Items

done!

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203538

Comment: So in simple words, first make sure you have resetUserPermissions from the command line and then by going from Finder Go command move to /user/local/your_directory, right click and on gear icon add read-write permissions to your user.

Comment: How does resetting user permissions fix issues with `/etc/sudoers`?

Answer (score 1):

If it still relevant this is my solution to this problem. I'm not doing boot into single user mode. It will work if you have the root password

```
su -
mount -uw /
chown root:wheel /etc/sudoers
chmod 440 /etc/sudoers
reboot
```