# Fixing /etc/sudoers file

Tags: high-sierra, sudo

I'm a systems admin for a company and was thrown into a horribly configured server. In the midst of my refactoring I was adding users to my `/etc/sudoers` file. I seem to have accidentally removed my server admin account from the sudoers file access.

I know what I did wrong (i accidentally commented out the `%admin` line) question being, how can I reinstate my server admin access in the file without having to restart anything.

Here's how it looks right now:

```
##
## User privilege specification
##
root ALL=(ALL) ALL
#%admin  ALL=(ALL) ALL
%superuser ALL=(ALL) ALL
"user1" ALL=(ALL) ALL
"user2" ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

Also note that my users do not have permission for `sudo` for some reason:

```
Realtor-Station-3-27:~ user1$ sudo -i

WARNING: Improper use of the sudo command could lead to data loss
or the deletion of important system files. Please double-check your
typing when using sudo. Type "man sudo" for more information.

To proceed, enter your password, or type Ctrl-C to abort.

Password:
user1 is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.
Realtor-Station-3-27:~ user1$
```

Comment: Boot into single user mode and fix the file :-)

Answer (score 16):

If you have access to finder and a system administrator account, you can fix this without a reboot by leveraging these.

Open up your finder and go to `/etc`. In here, you can view the details of the sudoers file, including permissions - screenshot below.

[image: screenshot showing where to change permissions on the sudoers file in Finder]

Change the permissions for "everyone" here to Read & Write.

At this time, you can edit yourself back into the file with any text editor. You will have to return permissions for "everyone" back to No Access before sudo will allow you to perform a `sudo`.

Comment: I found this answer more useful than doing it over CLI.

Comment: works for mac. you need to revert the access change after done

Answer (score 6):

Once you get things working again, you should make sure these lines exists at the bottom of your `/etc/sudoers` file:

```
## Read drop-in files from /private/etc/sudoers.d
## (the '#' here does not indicate a comment)
#includedir /private/etc/sudoers.d
```

Then make sure that you have a `/etc/sudoers.d/` directory. This is how mine looks:

```
> ls -ld /etc/sudoers.d
drwxr-xr-x 3 root wheel 96 Jul 31 20:59 /etc/sudoers.d/
```

Now you can effectively make changes to the `sudoers` file by adding a new file into the `/etc/sudoers.d/` folder. For example, I named mine `tjluoma` so the file `/etc/sudoers.d/tjluoma` (note the lack of filename extension, which seems to be a requirement) has my modifications to `sudoers` but I don’t risk causing global problems to `sudo` if there is a syntax error.

You can verify that your personal `sudoers` file is being read by using `sudo visudo -c` which will list all of the files that `sudo` will use, as shown here:

```
> sudo visudo -c
/etc/sudoers: parsed OK
/private/etc/sudoers.d/tjluoma: parsed OK
```

*(Note that `/private/etc/sudoers.d/` and `/etc/sudoers.d/` refer to the same folder.)*

Of course the best way to make changes to `/etc/sudoers` or your personal `sudoers` file is with `sudo visudo` or `sudo visudo -f /private/etc/sudoers.d/tjluoma` because it will check the syntax as part of the process of editing / saving, but we’ve all probably been guilty of not following that step

Comment: Thank you for mentioning *the requirement to NOT have filename extension* for files in `/etc/sudoers.d/` — this was the trouble in my case.

Answer (score 2):

I was unsuccessful in replacing the `/etc/sudoers` file with a fresh new file and changing its permission to `root:wheel` and `0440`.

Finally I had to go to Recovery Mode (restart → <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>)

1. Mount Macintosh HD through Disk Utility
2. Go to Terminal through Utilities
3. `cd /Macintosh HD/private/etc`
4. Edit `sudoers` file to correct the mistakes.
5. Save and change permissions if needed. `sudoers` file needs `root:wheel`.  If its not, `sudo` won't be run. `chown root:wheel sudoers`
6. I had also changed the permissions with `chmod 0440 sudoers` since I initially removed `sudoers` and created a fresh copy when I was logged in.

Comment: I cannot edit `/etc/sudoers` because **Permission Denied**

Answer (score 0):

So after banging my head for 2hrs and 100 different articles, I managed to brute my way through.

1. Use finder to change permissions of sudoers file. Right click>Get info>Sharing and Permissions.Change it for all parties including 'everyone' to read & write. Not sure if this step is necessary though.
2. Delete sudoers file from /etc/ using finder after making a copy of it.
3. Shift new sudoers file back to /etc/
4. Use this command to restore your sudoers file https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/394943