# How to fix Permission Denied error when starting up MongoDB

Tags: macos, command-line, install, permission

So I'm newbie to learning react and node and thought of building something based on MERN stack - I installed mongodb using `npm install -g mongodb` then it says its installed - then to create data directory for Monogo to use I ran `mkdir -p /data/db` and the response is `Permission Denied`.

To solve this I tried to do [Fixing /etc/sudoers file](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/317425/fixing-etc-sudoers-file) which hasn't led me anywhere either. Anyway when I run this command `mongod` it gives me shutting me down server message as below:

```
2019-03-29T13:30:02.772+1100 I CONTROL  [main] Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'
2019-03-29T13:30:02.792+1100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=2962 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=Farwas-MBP
2019-03-29T13:30:02.792+1100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v4.0.3
2019-03-29T13:30:02.792+1100 I CONTROL [initandlisten] git version: 7ea530946fa7880364d88c8d8b6026bbc9ffa48c
2019-03-29T13:30:02.792+1100 I CONTROL [initandlisten] allocator: system
2019-03-29T13:30:02.792+1100 I CONTROL [initandlisten] modules: none
2019-03-29T13:30:02.792+1100 I CONTROL [initandlisten] build environment:
2019-03-29T13:30:02.792+1100 I CONTROL [initandlisten] distarch: x86_64
2019-03-29T13:30:02.792+1100 I CONTROL [initandlisten] target_arch: x86_64
2019-03-29T13:30:02.792+1100 I CONTROL [initandlisten] options: {}
2019-03-29T13:30:02.792+1100 E STORAGE [initandlisten] Failed to set up listener: SocketException: Address already in use
2019-03-29T13:30:02.793+1100 I CONTROL [initandlisten] now exiting
2019-03-29T13:30:02.793+1100 I CONTROL [initandlisten] shutting down with code:48
```

Comment: You can actually edit your question directly by clicking on  the "edit" link beneath it. That's easier than putting a lot of things in comments.

Comment: I may be wrong, but I don't think the `sudoers` file has anything to do with your problem. You get the `Permission denied` error because the user you are logged in to is not allowed to create the `/data` directory. Can you add a link to the instructions you are following in setting this up (something must have told you to do `mkdir -p /data/db` for instance), will be easier to understand where things go amiss that way.

Comment: Sorry about that didn't know that... 
And the user Im signed in is the admin user - like it authorizes every change on the system then why `Permission denied` - I came across this one to setup monogdb and followed this. https://codingthesmartway.com/the-mern-stack-tutorial-building-a-react-crud-application-from-start-to-finish-part-2/ Apparently my friend;s system gives the same response as per the link

Comment: You need to create the directory by running `sudo mkdir -p /data/db` (and enter your password again when prompted).

Comment: But from looking at the log output it seems that there is already a mongodb service running (`Failed to set up listener: SocketException: Address already in use`). Can you check whether this is the case, and then kill this process first?

Answer (score 1):

Use homebrew to install `mongodb` so you don’t need root would be my help to offer.

- https://brew.sh

Then

```
brew install mongodb
brew services start mongodb
```

---

As to sudoers, boot into recovery and use terminal (utilities menu) to mount the filesystem and fix it [per this answer from your linked question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/334984/5472). Older os can use single user mode, but terminal in recovery is nicer to use.

Comment: nop - it still shuts down the server - the sudo fixes is all done but it doesn't let me in - keeps telling me `Permission Denied` - im hopeless

Comment: How about posting the contents (or paste bin / gist) of `tail -8 /usr/local/var/log/mongodb/mongo.log ` (and if you haven’t created the folder where the databases get stores - then try `mkdir -p /usr/local/var/mongodb` )

Comment: Restart that computer - you have another process that has claimed the port needed by mongod process - this has nothing to do with permissions. Excellent work getting to the actual problem by looking at the logs @fahz