# How can I change the ownership of the unwritable directories for Homebrew?

Tags: terminal, bash, homebrew, permission

I had admin account before and I deleted the admin and made the user as admin because it was bit of pain in neck. This is now the admin user called zuhairhallak. Before, installing Homebrew, it was just user without any privileges. I want to fix that. I tried to remove Homebrew but it did not let me.

```
zuhairs-mbp:~ zuhairhallak$ sudo chown -R $zuhairhallak /usr/local/share/aclocal /usr/local/share/doc /usr/local/share/info /usr/local/share/locale /usr/local/share/man /usr/local/share/man/man1 /usr/local/share/man/man3 /usr/local/share/man/man5 /usr/local/share/man/man7 /usr/local/share/man/man8 /usr/local/share/zsh /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions
Password:
chown: /usr/local/share/aclocal: illegal user name
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) As stated, your query is not clear. Kindly consider [editing](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/354373/edit) your post and clearly specify the problem that you are facing and any salvage actions that you have attempted. It generally helps to mention the make and model of your hardware along with the version of operating system software (iOS/macOS) running on your device.

Comment: I suspect this has nothing to do with unwritable, and I doubt your user name contains $ - is that your actual question? The `brew doctor` command will give you the syntax to fix things, too but perhaps you want to learn why yours causes an error.

Answer (score 1):

I would start with a simpler command.

```
sudo chown -R 501 /usr/local/share/aclocal
```

Use a user number instead of name to see if that’s he error. Also, do one directory first to be sure where the error arises. You could even skip the `-R` if the above command fails to further reduce the variables in play.

Comment: zuhairs-mbp:etc zuhairhallak$ sudo chown -R 501 /usr/local/share/aclocal
sudo: /etc/sudoers is owned by uid 501, should be 0
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin

Comment: @Tahan See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/157772/sudo-etc-sudoers-is-owned-by-uid-501-should-be-0 for how to fix this.