# Can't fix sudoers permission on osx mojave

Tags: mojave, recovery, sudo

A friend had borrowed my macbook air running osx mojave and somehow managed to change the ownership of the `/etc/sudoers` file to userid 501 (rather than 0 which it should be). Because of this, I can't become a superuser to get anything done on my machine (upgrades etc.)

Various fora on the net suggested that I boot into single user mode, mount the partitions and manually edit /etc/private/sudoers. However, I can't seem to do this. After getting into "recovery mode", I do a `mount -uw /` to get the filesystems mounted but can't find a `sudoers` file in either `/etc/` or `/private/etc`. I did a global search using `find / | grep -i sudo` but couldn't find anything either.

How do I fix this? If I can mount the right partition while in this shell, I should be able to to fix it but can't seem to do that.

Comment: Do you boot into single user or recovery mode? These are different, please clarify. This will also help to figure out whether your question is a duplicate of an existing one (as it currently looks) or whether you need an other solution?

Comment: I booted into recovery mode. Several websites suggested holding Cmd-S to boot into single user mode but that didn't work. I then read about using Cmd-R to boot into recovery mode and I have a GUI with `macOS utilities` mentioned with options like (restore from time machine backup, reinstall macOS etc.)

Comment: @NoufalIbrahim It depends on your Mac: With T2-chip you can usually boot to recovery mode only. Since rec mode boots from a different volume, you have to replace /etc with /Volumes/[main boot volume]/etc.

Comment: I will check. Though a `find` should have shown me if it were mounted.

Comment: @klanomath You're right. That partition wasn't mounted.

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/353478/9058 describes how to fix this via Recovery Mode.