# sudo: /etc/sudoers is owned by uid 501, should be 0 not mounting for recovery

Tags: terminal, hard-drive, disk-utility, sudo

I edited my `etc/sudoers` file to try to disable the requirement for sudo password.

Now I can't run sudo commands in the terminal. I get the following error:

```
sudo: /etc/sudoers is owned by uid 501, should be 0
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin
```

I am following the instructions on:
[sudo: /etc/sudoers is owned by uid 501, should be 0](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/157772/sudo-etc-sudoers-is-owned-by-uid-501-should-be-0)

But I am getting an issue on the first line when I try to run the mount command:

```
mount -uw /
```

brings about the error:

```
mount_apfs: volume could not be mounted: Operation not permitted
mount: / failed with 77
```

I also ran the in recovery mode to look at the disk utility. I think my Mac is running on a partitioned drive because "Macintosh HD" is greyed out and it says it can't be mounted because the computer has detected a problem with it so it can't be unlocked.

The there is a drive there called "Macintosh HD - Data Data" that seems to have all my stuff on it. so my laptop must be running off that.

Any ideas how I can fix it?

Comment: Precisely what Mac & OS are you running? Single User mode can't be accessed on newer systems.

Comment: Several of the answers there don't work in recent versions of macOS due to changes in how the system volume is set up and the deprecation of single-user mode. Try [my answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/157772/sudo-etc-sudoers-is-owned-by-uid-501-should-be-0/394943#394943), it should still work.

Comment: @Tetsujin I am using Catalan 10.15.5

Comment: @GordonDavisson Thanks so much it worked. what i was originally trying to do was remove passwords from sudo by editing the sudoers file with: 

`%admin ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL` it didn't seem to work though. it threw the error you helped me fix above